# Modificar elementos repetidos de un arreglo con un contador - Javascript

Tags: javascript, nodejs, filtro, map

La idea del siguiente script es iterar un arreglo y conforme se detecte que un elemento es similar a otro, independientemente de su índice, indique con el número **2**, que éste se encuentra repetido. En el caso de que haya 3 iguales, ese 2 pase a ser **3**. Así sucesivamente con cada similitud encontrada. Si otro elemento está repetido, lo mismo. Por ejemplo, si se le pasa al programa un arreglo como este: ['Sol', 'Luna', 'Sol', 'Asteroide', 'Sol', 'Luna'], el objeto a retornar y visualizar en la consola debería ser ['Sol', 'Luna', 'Sol2', 'Asteroide', 'Sol3', 'Luna2']. Estoy intentando con este código, pero no estaría funcionando:

```
let contador = 2;

const nuevoArreglo = arr => {
    return arr.map((val, index) => {
        return arr.indexOf(val) !== index ? `${val}${contador++}` : val;
    })
};
```

Dejo a continuación lo que sale en pantalla:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

**Nota**: Esos valores son pusheados a un array y luego la función se encarga de retornar el nuevo objeto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creo un array de strings

```
let arr = ['Sol', 'Luna', 'Sol', 'Asteroide', 'Sol', 'Luna'];
```

Creo un **contador** que es un **objeto literal** para almacenar los valores del array **arr** como **clave**

```
let contador = {};
```

Esto para tener el siguiente formato

```
{
    Sol: 3,
    Luna: 2,
    Asteroide: 1
}
```

La idea es estar modificando cada clave del objeto literal.

Creo un nuevo array con **map** considerando el objeto literal, **si la clave no existe en el objeto literal la defino e inicio en 0.**

```
let nuevoArray = arr.map((val, index) => {
    if (!contador[val]) {
        contador[val] = 0;
    }
    contador[val]++;

    return contador[val] > 1 ? `${val}${contador[val]}` : val;
});
```

Código completo

```js
let arr = ['Sol', 'Luna', 'Sol', 'Asteroide', 'Sol', 'Luna'];

let contador = {};

let nuevoArray = arr.map((val, index) => {
    if (!contador[val]) {
        contador[val] = 0;
    }
    contador[val]++;

    return contador[val] > 1 ? `${val}${contador[val]}` : val;
});

console.log('nuevo array', nuevoArray)
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Clinton por tu respuesta. Muy clara y concisa.